# IEnumerable<XElement> is fetching same element more than once

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml, ienumerable

I'm trying to fetch xml data using `XDocument` and `Xelement` in `C#`. I am using `IEnumerable<XElement>` to iterate through all elements I want to fetch. My problem is, `IEnumerable<XElement>` is fetching same data many times and when i use `foreach` loop, it loops more than the count of elements in my xml file. It's fetching same thing in each loop. Any suggestions ?

**My XML File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<SYSTEM SelectedConfiguration = "5840-0000-0001">
  <Configuration Name = "5840-0000-0001">
     <Users>
        <User>
          <Name>Lebron</Name>
          <Surname>James</Surname>
          <Adress>asdfgh</Adress>
          <Phone>1234</Phone>
          <Gender>Male</Gender>
          <Country>USA</Country>
        </User>
        <User>
          <Name>Kevin</Name>
          <Surname>Durand</Surname>
          <Adress>asdfghasdfgh</Adress>
          <Phone>4567</Phone>
          <Gender>Male</Gender>
          <Country>USA</Country>
        </User>
        <User>
          <Name>Stephen</Name>
          <Surname>Curry</Surname>
          <Adress>zxcv</Adress>
          <Phone>1267</Phone>
          <Gender>Male</Gender>
          <Country>USA</Country>
        </User>
    </Users>
  </Configuration>  
</SYSTEM>
```

**My Code:**

```
 XDocument devices = XDocument.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\Users.xml");
                    XElement conf = devices.Root.Element("Configuration");

                  /*
                    IEnumerable<XElement> childElements =
                        from el in conf.Element("Instruments").Elements("Instrument")
                        select el;
                   */
                    IEnumerable<XElement> childElements = conf.Element("Users").Elements("User");
                    int counter = childElements.Count();
                    foreach (XElement el in childElements)
                    {


                            DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)dataGridView1.Rows[0].Clone();
                            row.Cells[0].Value = el.Element("Name").Value.ToString();
                            row.Cells[1].Value = el.Element("Surname").Value.ToString();
                            row.Cells[2].Value = el.Element("Adress").Value.ToString();

                            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
                           // if (counter-- <= 1)
                               // return;
                    }
```

**The results I got:**

[Click here to see the image](http://resimag.com/p1/a57af250951.png)

[Click here to see the image 2](http://resimag.com/p1/ae0131ebe1a.png)

[Click here to see the image 3](http://resimag.com/p1/2bf133f677f.png)

As seen in the images, there are more than one Lebron James or Kevin Durand and `foreach`is looping through each combination of these nodes as seen in the Image 3.

Edit 1:

Program is looping back to `IEnumerable<XElement> childElements = conf.Element("Users").Elements("User");` line several times. Counter is getting 3 again and again.

Comment: No, your images show Node 0 with one name, and Node 1 with another. If you expand the node, you see base classes, not other objects. Is your counter really not 3 ?

Comment: How does this code `dataGridView1.Rows[0].Clone()` not produce an `IndexOutOfRangeException` on the first go, where is the `Rows[0]` coming from?

Comment: I would suggest try to call `dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();` at the start of your routine.

Comment: @Holger it loops back to IEnumerable<XElement> childElements = conf.Element("Users").Elements("User"); line several times. I didn't understand. My counter is getting 3 but it gets 3 again and again if I did not put a return at the end of code.

Comment: @RandRandom dataGridView is coming with 1 empty line at the start if you enable adding new rows.

Comment: You are saying that the program is looping back to `IEnumerable<XElement> childElements = conf.Element("Users").Elements("User");` for the program to do so, there has to be an outer loop that you aren't showing. The inner loop `foreach (XElement el in childElements)` can't make the program go to lines outside the loop.

Comment: BTW your problem seems to be easily solvable if you just use a breakpoint and step through your code and see what actually happens. have a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me, please have a look.

```
XDocument devices = XDocument.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\Users.xml");
XElement conf = devices.Root.Element("Configuration");

List < string > list = new List < string > ();
IEnumerable < XElement > childElements = conf.Element("Users").Elements("User");
var dataList = childElements.Select(el => new {
 Name = el.Element("Name").Value.ToString(),
  Surname = el.Element("Surname").Value.ToString(),
  Adress = el.Element("Adress").Value.ToString()
});

foreach(var userInfo in dataList) {
 list.Add($ "{userInfo.Name}:{userInfo.Surname}:{userInfo.Adress}");
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem. Thanks. Can you please explain what is the difference between Select() and foreach(XElement ..).

Comment: not sure about the exact reason but IEnumerable request the next element only when it needed. Maybe some interference with grid implementation. Have you tried your code without grid (e.g. to store element in a list)?

Comment: No I haven't. I tried to use data directly in dataGridView.